# If I add an index exemption, will it delete already existing single-field indexes?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have a database with hundreds of millions o documents. There is a field in each document that is very big (deeply nested), and I did not add an exemption to it from the beginning.

My question is: If I add the exemption now, I know that it will prevent to index this field for further documents added to the database, but will it delete the already existing index too and free space?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Further documents will not be added to the index table with an exception and existing indexes will be disabled.

> An indexing exemption overrides the database-wide automatic index settings.

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview

Comment: Will be disabled, yes. I read the whole documentation. My question is: will it free the associated space, which means that I will pay less for firestore storage next month? Or it will just be disabled and not deleted?

Comment: You will not have to pay for it. by being automatic, it is managed by the instance while it is "enabled" - disabling it, removes it.